# Send HTML email with Mysql data into a table from within application

Tags: c#, mysql, html

I have an application that i'm using to send an email that contains an entire table and i don't know how to get that dynamic data there. I'M SURE i have to use a for loop but i don't know how to word it to get the rows of data.

Here is what i have so far:

```
    msg.To.Add(selected);//put in custom account info
        msg.Subject = "Message Subject";
        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
        msg.Body = "<html>"+
        "<body>"+
        "<center>"+
        "<h2>Your entire inventory:</h2>"+
        "<table>"+
        "<th>Product</th>"+
        //for each loop

        "<th>Quantity</th>"+
        //for each loop
            "</body>"+
            "</html>";
```

Let me know if you need any other code.

Comment: Sounds like the Product info is coming from a database.. Can you show your code to pull that data?

Comment: Where is the Product and Quantity data coming from?

Comment: You should start with getting an idea of what you want the output to look like.  As is, you're creating some invalid HTML.

Comment: the product is coming from the database. i'm not pulling anything from it yet though because i don't know how to go about it.

Comment: right now i just want it to appear in an email, then i'll actually get the html up to snuff. i know html css and some php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would avoid building HTML using string concatenation.  Not only can it make your code awkward, but you also risk accidental mistakes in encoding your output.  One alternative is to use LINQ to XML to build your HTML.  The code would look something like this:

```
var html = new XDocument(
    new XElement("html",
        new XElement("body",
            new XElement("h2", "Your entire inventory:"),
            new XElement("table",
                new XElement("tr",
                    new XElement("th", "Product"),
                    from item in orders
                    select new XElement("td", item.ProductName)),
                new XElement("tr",
                    new XElement("th", "Quantity"),
                    from item in orders
                    select new XElement("td", item.Quantity))))));

msg.Body = html.ToString();
```

Comment: what type of object is 'item' in your example so i can pull it from mysql and make it that object to get the product and quantity? i kind of see where your going with this.

Comment: If you're just displaying ProductName and Quantity, then it should be an object with those properties.  Just come up with a query that contains the data you need.

Comment: this worked great to lay it out and @stephen's example did great to get it there. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you already have the [MySQL Connector for .NET](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/1.0.html). Here's some code that should get you going in the right direction. If you don't know how to read from a database using C# you should read up on that. [MySQL Connector Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-programming.html)

Just a simple Product class to hold what you need.

```
public class Product
{
    public String ProductName { get; set; }
    public Int32 Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Here is just a quick database class overview.

```
 public class DB
{
    string connString = "Your Database Connection String";

    public List<Product> GetProductsAndQuantity()
    {
        string query = "SELECT product, quantity FROM yourTable";
        List<Product> prodList = new List<Product>();

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            try
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    // Create new Product
                    Product p = new Product();
                    p.ProductName = (String)reader[0];
                    p.Quantity = (Int32)reader[1];
                    // Add product to list
                    prodList.Add(p);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                reader.Close();
            }
        }

        return prodList;
    }
}
```

This is where you're building your email.

```
DB db = new DB();

List<Product> prodList = db.GetProductsAndQuantity();
            msg.Body...
            msg.Body += " <table> <tr><th>Product</th> <th>Quantity</th></tr> ";

            foreach (Product p in prodList)
            {
                msg.Body += "<tr><td>" + p.ProductName + "</td><td>"
                         + p.Quantity + "</td></tr>";
            }

            msg.Body += "</table> ";
```

Comment: I used your information to get the data from my mysql DB and @jacob's example to layout my html email thank you both!