# Add style to Xelement in C# for an HTML email

Tags: c#, html, styles, xelement

I just had this html email figured out and now i need to style it so that i can get a space between these 2 columns on my table here is my code:

```
    var html = new XDocument(
 new XElement("html",
     new XElement("body",
         new XElement("h2", "Your entire inventory:"),
         new XElement("table",
             new XElement("tr",
                 new XElement("th", "Product"),

                 new XElement("th", "Quantity")),
                    new XElement("tr",
                 from item in prodList
                 select new XElement("td", item.ProductName, new XElement("td", item.Quantity), new XElement("tr")))
                 ))));
```

This is the output i get:

```
Your entire inventory:

                Product                    Quantity
Nissin rich & savory chicken bw - 6 pack  5
The Zombie Survival Guide                 3
Maruchan Ramen Noodle Soup                5
Generic Tomatoes, Whole                   2
```

So i need to figure out how to put style in the tags to get the padding/border etc in the email

Comment: I sure hope the output you get is XML and not the text you posted. If not, why use `XDocument` at all?

Comment: my last problem i had getting the data from mysql to an html email led me there. here is my last problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9167208/send-html-email-with-mysql-data-into-a-table-from-within-application/9169987#9169987

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `XElement` structure is fairly broken (you’re defining `tr` elements within `td` elements within other `td` elements); it’s rather unpredictable how a browser would render the result. Here is how it looks:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h2>Your entire inventory:</h2>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Nissin rich &amp; savory chicken bw - 6 pack<td>5</td><tr /></td>
        <td>The Zombie Survival Guide<td>3</td><tr /></td>
        <td>Maruchan Ramen Noodle Soup<td>5</td><tr /></td>
        <td>Generic Tomatoes, Whole<td>2</td><tr /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

To start off, you should fix your HTML generation code (see below).

Since you’re intending to use your HTML in emails, you should preferably steer clear of  embedded style sheets (despite their appeal for avoiding code repetition). Some email (web)clients, most notably Gmail, simply ignore embedded style sheets (refer to [Using CSS and HTML in Email Newsletters](http://groundwire.org/support/articles/css-and-email-newsletters)). In most cases, it’s safer to use inline styles for HTML emails.

To introduce some spacing between your two columns, you could define an line `style="padding-right:50px;"` attribute on all cells within the left column; this would ensure that there are 50 pixels of whitespace between the longest product name and the quantities column.

```
var html = new XDocument(
    new XElement("html",
        new XElement("body",
            new XElement("h2", "Your entire inventory:"),
            new XElement("table",
                new XElement("tr",
                new XElement("th", "Product", 
                    new XAttribute("style", "padding-right:50px;")),
                new XElement("th", "Quantity")),
            from item in prodList
            select new XElement("tr",
                new XElement("td", item.ProductName, 
                    new XAttribute("style", "padding-right:50px;")),
                new XElement("td", item.Quantity))))));
```

The above code would generate:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h2>Your entire inventory:</h2>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th style="padding-right:50px;">Product</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="padding-right:50px;">Nissin rich &amp; savory chicken bw - 6 pack</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="padding-right:50px;">The Zombie Survival Guide</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="padding-right:50px;">Maruchan Ramen Noodle Soup</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="padding-right:50px;">Generic Tomatoes, Whole</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Defining the style of an HTML element is usually done using CSS:

```
new XElement("html",
    new XElement("head",
        new XElement("style",
            new XAttribute("type", "text/css"),
            "td { border: 1px solid red; }"
        )
    ),
    new XElement("body", ...
```

Comment: well i knew it would be css but i didn't know how to tell C# that i'm using CSS. but now i do thanks to XAttribute let met try this and i'll get back to you. thanks

Comment: Be careful; some email (web)clients, most notably Gmail, ignore embedded style sheets within HTML mail.

Comment: i'm using gmail to view the html actually. and inside of chrome as well. thank you for the advice